# How to make a parameter only count once in Anylogic model during simulation?

Tags: anylogic

I am having a hard time trying to solve a very easy issue I can imagine, but I just can't see it.
Namely, I am building a dynamic simulation model which calculates accumulated costs and benefits.
However, I have introduced a 5 year time span for the model but there are certain costs and benefits which occur only once (in the first year for example). But currently, the model is using these parameters in each simulation for **every year**. How can model it such that these values are only taken into the simulation once?

Surely there is some kind of formula which could help me with this. The AnyLogic support page did not help me either.

Comment: Please share more details on your specific implementation, screenshots, etc. What is the experiment setup? How do you use the parameters... Welcome to SOF :)

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is part of the model where the problem lies: https://imgur.com/cFo82D8   I have added the red text to clarify what the distinction is between the two costs. Track Improvement costs are only once whilst Organisation Costs are present every year. That is also why the Promotor Funds Variation flow has the formula = TicketRevenue+LackOfPromotorFunds-OrganisationCosts-TrackImprovements. But this obviously isn't correct since the track improvement costs occur only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applying values that change over time, you should use a "Dynamic Variable" object and set it to 0 after one year as follows (assuming "999" is replaced yb whatever value you want):
[image: aram to dynVar]

Comment: Great @Xander .If it does, please mark the answer as "useful" (up-arrow next to it) so others can find it easily in the future. Welcome to SOF (also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info how this place works)

Comment: At first I thought it had worked, but unfortunately the costs are still accumulating over time :( It doesn't stop after 1 year. It's quite weird because I don't get any errors when applying your formula, but for some reason the system does not take it into consideration

Comment: sorry, my bad. this is (as it says) the "default value" applied only once at the model start. Check my new revised reply above

Comment: Yes, wonderful! I have tested it and it works now :) Did not know to use a dynamic variable, but now it makes sense. Thank you!!

Comment: Is there a way in which I can extend a dynamic variable even further? So that in year 0 it is 999, year 1 it is 500, year 2 it is 250 and so on?

Comment: Sure. Either write a specific function or just use nested if-else statements like "time<1*year() ? 999 : time<2*year ? : 250 : ... . But you might want to checkout the table-function element as well (see help and tutorials)